# OpenSSL how ASN1_TYPE and ASN1_ITEM are related

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1

I'm trying to digitally sign a pdf document using OpenSSL library. Now I want to get a digest from the pdf document content. I only found method which create the digest from `ASN1_ITEM`. But what I have is `ASN1_OCTET_STRING` object which I can convert to `ASN1_TYPE` if needed. I suppose that there should be some way to convert `ASN1_TYPE` or `ASN1_OCTET_STRING` into `ASN1_ITEM`. But I don't understand how `ASN1_TYPE` and `ASN1_TYPE` are related.

P.S. Would be grateful if someone share some kind of proper documentation of OpenSSL. What I could find are mostly source files without proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you write "what I have is `ASN1_OCTET_STRING` object", the following snippet, found under the NOTES section in the [documentation of the `ASN1_STRING` utilities](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8.html),  seems useful:

> Almost all ASN1 types in OpenSSL are represented as an `ASN1_STRING`
>   structure. Other types such as `ASN1_OCTET_STRING` are simply
>   typedef'ed to `ASN1_STRING` and the functions call the `ASN1_STRING`
>   equivalents.

(You can verify that this happens in [`ossl_typ.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h#L25), it is actually not a `typedef` but a `#define`)

That same documentation page gives a function `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8()` that you can use to get a representation of the data as an `unsigned char *` as well as its length. Once you have that, you can [calculate a digest to your liking](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests).

This is not an answer to your question "how `ASN1_TYPE` and `ASN1_ITEM` are related" but it seems to cover the problem that you describe. If that is not the case, please clarify.